# Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+. Cannot pinpoint location in code where error occured

Tags: c#, exception, gdi+, system.drawing, unhandled

There are many variations of this question but I am unable to find the answer I need.  The only thing I have to show is the stack trace (which is similar to other stack traces posted for this question)  From the trace, I cannot determine where in the code this is happening.  At the time, the code should have been updating and adding to several listView controls and doing some file writes.  This answers to this question have run the gamut from resources, file locks, permissions, fonts, multi-threading and various other things but I don't have enough info to get started.  If anyone can shine some light on what this stack is telling me and either provide a solid idea/answer or even a strategy of how to go about diagnosing or trapping the problem, I would be grateful (I believe I have this formatted correctly but apologies if I didn't make it readable enough)

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException was unhandled
  _HResult=-2147467259
  _message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  HResult=-2147467259
  IsTransient=false
  Message=A generic error occurred in GDI+.
  Source=System.Drawing
  ErrorCode=-2147467259
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font, SizeF layoutArea, StringFormat stringFormat)
       at System.Drawing.Graphics.MeasureString(String text, Font font, Int32 width)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ThreadExceptionDialog..ctor(Exception t)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(Exception t)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.OnThreadException(Exception e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Alpha_Strategy_Engine.Program.Main() in c:\Users\Jeffery\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Alpha Strategy Engine\Program.cs:line 50
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Try to check the params of the MeasureString call! Including the Font (is it null?), the Size (is it positive? is it too large?) the text ( is it too long?)

Comment: Well, the stack trace tells the tale.  A timer's Tick event handler died with an unhandled exception and when Winforms tried to tell the user about the mishap, it in turn died when trying to display the dialog.  We can't see what that Tick event handler does but the 98% odds are that it died on the exact same problem that made the dialog keel over.   Task Manager can usually show you the problem.  Processes tab, View > Select Columns and tick USER objects and GDI objects.  Observe the values for your program while you are using it.  Steadily climbing numbers spell doom.

Comment: TaW - I guess I should be able to check that value after a crash?

Comment: Hans, this is a good idea...I'm not handling any exceptions in that timer.   If the GDI and User objects are growing, is this because I am not explicitly freeing these up somehow?  What are the most common ways these mistakes are made?

Comment: Hans, after 1 day, User Objs = 274 and GDI objs = 120.  Is that high?

Comment: @HansPassant  Hi Hans - I think I was responding incorrectly by not using the "@" in front of your name.  In my process, GDI stays about constant at 120 but User Objs keep growing, now at 314.  Still seems small with a 10k limit but any advice on how to close object handles in use?  (I'm using the gdiview tool recommended by Mark below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like one of your threads is bombing,
have you checked for leaks in your handling of GDI resources?

Here is a tool that claims to detect GDI leaks:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/20264/GDI-Leak-Detector-A-special-debugger-to-detect-and

And a tool to simply view the amount of GDI handles (poor man's debugging):
http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html

And an msdn blog post about it:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsui_team/archive/2013/04/23/debugging-a-gdi-resource-leak.aspx

Comment: I'm not explicitly spawning any threads and am trying to marshall control-affecting events back to the form but I could be missing one I suppose.  I'm not super conversant with multi-threading.  Could you suggest how to check for leaks as you suggest?

Comment: ok those are some good ideas.  I will check them out and report back on what I found.

Comment: You might wanna focus on code that runs inside timers.
Are you calling Refresh() in a timer?

Comment: No I'm not calling Refresh() in the timer event.  Do you recommend that?

Comment: @Algodevguy: no, i would not recommend that, but i saw a Timer in the stacktrace